# Circular definition of set? Can someone spot contradiction/expose the tautology?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am wondering about the definition of a set $C$ for some diagonalisable matrix $\Theta_s = F^s$ where all eigenvalues of $F$ are between zero and one but are strictly ordered, so that we have some that are close to unity and some that are further away and there is a clear separation between those two groups. Then we have for all $\beta \in C$ and all $\gamma \notin C$
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{s \rightarrow \infty}\frac{||{\beta^{\prime}\Theta_{s}}||}{||{\gamma^{\prime}\Theta_{s}||}}=0. 
\end{eqnarray}

The idea is that this definition ought to pin down $C$ and $C^{\perp}$ simultaneously. However, when working with this definition I found myself using tautological arguments. I have posed a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1935570/circular-logic-in-set-definition-tautology) but was too general. So here is the specific case.

Thanks so much for your help!

Edit: in light of a useful comment: I expect the set $C$ to be the linear subspace of $R^{p}$ that contains those linear combinations of the columns of $\Theta_s$ whose norm decays faster than any other linear combination making the statement true. This arose in a discussion with someone and $C^{\perp}$ is hoped to be the orthogonal complement to $C$.

Comment: What exactly do you expect the set $C$ to be? You have to be careful that $C^\perp$ is not the same as the complement of $C$.

Comment: Depending on how $\Theta_s$ depends on $s$, you may be able to prove that there is a unique $C$ that satisfies your property, and _once you have conducted that proof_ you can define $C$ to be that set. But the property does not _in itself_ define anything.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments @IBWiglin.

Comment: It still looks like you're expecting $\gamma\notin C$ to mean the same as $\gamma\in C^\bot$, which is definitely not the case.

Comment: @HenningMakholm that was hoped to be the case. Can you explain why? I also disagree with the usefulness of this definition but can't put my finger on why. More edits added.

Comment: Let the eigenvectors of $F$ in increasing order of eigenvalue be $v_1,\ldots,v_p$. For any $0\le k\le p$, the set $C = \operatorname{span}\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ satisfies your condition. Equivalently, pick any threshold $\theta\in[0,1]$ and define $C$ to be the span of all eigenvectors whose eigenvalue is less than $\theta$.

Comment: @Hirek: For example in $\mathbb R^2$, if $C$ is the $x$-axis, then $(1,1)\notin C$, but $(1,1)$ is not in $C^\bot$.

Comment: Thank you @HenningMakholm could you perhaps also point to internal logic violations? When asked to prove things about this space I found myself having to assume the condition to be true in order to check, which is circular logic.